# Inserting commas or spaces into a long output of jQuery's .text() return

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to make a bookmarklet that will spit out the text of all links with a class of author. So far, I have this:

```
/// Stuff to load jQuery into the bookmarklet
    var authors = $(".author");var names = authors.text();alert(names);
```

The only issue is that it returns a long list of blabber,

```
JohnDoeMaryDoeEddieDoe
```

I need to append a comma or space to the end of each authors name, But I'm unsure how to do it.

```
$(".author"); + ",";
```

Simply appends a comma to the end of the entire string, And not individual authors/names, as does:

```
authors.text() + ","
```

Anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are retrieving the content of every element that matches your selector. According to the documentation for `.text`:

> The result of the .text() method is a string **containing the combined text of all matched elements**.

You could loop over each element with [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map), retrieve the element's text, and then join the resulting array with [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var names = $(".author").map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(", ");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/E3ba9/

Comment: This was brilliant and clean enough for me to get the multiple selected values:
`$("#ddlMultiCountyList_baseDropDownList option:selected").map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(", ");
"Citrus, Desoto"`